# Relationship between Gaussian and bisectional curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $f:\mathbb CP^1\to X$ be an smooth embedding which its image is the curve $C$ where $X$ is a Kähler manifold. Do we have that $$\sup_{\mathbb CP^1}K(f^*\omega)<\sup_C K(\omega),$$where $K(f^*\omega)$ denotes the Gaussian curvature of pullback of metric and $K(\omega)$ is the bisectional curvature?

Comment: If it is complex-differentiable then $C$ is saddle, by Gauss formula the intrinsic curvature of $C$ is smaller than the curvature of $X$ in the tangent direction. Hence you get $\le$ in your inequality, which implies $<$ in most of the cases. If the surface is just smooth then no hope.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin I'm not sure if I follow. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Well, what is the problem?